# Assiging values in Ruby using PHP equivalent for loop (I'm using Ruby on Rails)

Tags: arrays, ruby

I would like to ask what is the equivalent of the following PHP code in Ruby:

```php
for ($x = 0; $x <= 10; $x++) {
  $array[] = $x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ruby offers quite a few ways to do this:

Using a `Range`:

```rb
array = (0..10).to_a

# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Using `#times`:

```rb
array = 11.times.to_a

# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

If you really want to use a for loop:

```rb
array = []

for x in 0..10 do
  array << x
end

# => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

etc etc, check out the docs for [`Enumerator`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerator) and [`Enumerable`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/Enumerable.html).